# What's wrong with this calculation?

Tags: php

Consider this markup:

```
<?php
$drill = 0;
$result = '';
$dynamicD = rand(5,15);
$num01 = $dynamicD-4;
$placeholder = $num01.'+4';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if(empty($_POST["drill"])){
        $humanErr = "Empty";
    }
    else {
        $drill = $_POST["drill"];
        if($drill !== $dynamicD) {
            $result = "No";
        }
        else {
            $result = "Yes";
        }
    };
};
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
      <p>Correct Answer: <?php echo $dynamicD ?></p>
      <p>Does this work? <?php echo "$result";?></p>
      <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="drill">Can you solve it?</label>
          <input type="text" name="drill" id="drill" maxlengh="2" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder ?>"  required="true" />
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="check">Check</button>
     </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically it generates "random" number, insert it as a drill, and then let the user submit his answer. The problem is that the answer is always "NO"*.

I tried to separate the condition to this:

```
if($drill > $dynamicD) { $result = "bigger" }
elseif ($drill < $dynamicD) { $result = "smaller" }
```

and so on - but can't understand the logic of the $result (sometime bigger, sometime smaller, but i ALWAYS enter $dynamicD...).

What am i doing wrong here???

---

EDIT:

- As the comments points, every time the page submit it generates new numbers. The first time the code execute is the only time that correct answer would be equal to the numbers that display. After the first submit there is a gap.

**Note for future readers**: The above code extracted and simplified from bigger and much complex system. Not something that anyone would want to just copy-paste.

The solution i choose was to store the dynamically created vars on a `session` and re-declare if the `answer` is correct.
Would love to hear about other ways (not client side).

Comment: `$drill = +$_POST['drill'];` should do it. HTML values are Strings.

Comment: ^ or change `!==` to `!=`, or `$drill = (int)$_POST["drill"];`

Comment: Your flow is: generate a number, show this and allow input. On submit - generate a new number then test against the old number.

Comment: @StackSlave this didn't fix it..

Comment: @user3783243 believe me i already tried that.

Comment: @jeff care to show me?

Comment: Are you comparing against the displayed number or a random number? I thought it was like a slot machine. Try to hit the random number

Comment: @user3783243 LOL, So first I generate a number, then declare new var which is the number of subtracting 4 from the original number. I do that in order to generate a math drill that will look like number+4=user input. If that equal to the original number the answer should be YES. well... NO.

Comment: So you either need to store `$dynamicD` in a cookie or session variable and then compare against that on the load... or you can store in a hidden input. Cookie and hidden input can be read by user easily.

Comment: Can't understand the logic. The user's input compared to what?? The prev session??

Comment: If you want `rand(1, 10)`, just do that.

Comment: @StackSlave if i just wanted to generate random number i wouldn't wasting this past 3 hours...

Comment: Your `$dynamicD` will change every page load. If you just want them to guess the number shown on the Client, then do the comparison on the Client.

Comment: So $dynamicD changes every load. then when i submit i compare user input the newly $dynamicD which i print in order to check it. So i thought. Are you suggesting that the number that printed isn't the same as the real number on $dynamicD? I probably will do that client side but can't understand what is going on and how to fix this code.

Comment: Even if you use AJAX *(which I recommend instead of archaic form submission)* when a PHP page executes it runs fresh before anything is sent to the Browser. So, when you submit, it's a different value.

Comment: Effectively you have this https://3v4l.org/mWIWc but `$dynamicD = 5;` rotates so you are in a game of odds for when it will match, and what the last input was

Comment: @StackSlave this what i thought. But how can i get this newly number? i thought that if i print it i will see the fresh one not the previously. AND how it gives me a number on first load?? Can't understand the logic here. As for client side/AJAX etc - I know how to do that but i want to understand why this not work and how it could be fixed.

Comment: @user3783243 Exactly. So i understand that this sort of things couldn't be done with php itself???

Comment: You need to store the value in some persistent storage. Simplest and also least secure would be `<input type="hidden" name="dynamic" value="<?php echo $dynamicD;?>" />` Then use that as `$drill != $_POST['dynamic']`

Comment: @user3783243 thank you. After some sleep i solve that with setting session with dynamicD and placeholder. If the answer correct i unset it and if not the previous info there. I keep this question for future folks.